# Set fixed font in Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-canvas

I have an app which counts up from 1 to 100, showing the count-up on the screen.
I have a custom font. The problem is that the numbers keep jumping left and right as it counts up. I draw the numbers by drawing on a canvas, using graphics.Paint.

How can I set the font to be fixed and not jumping around?

Comment: Could you post some code? It sounds like the problem might be in the way you're positioning the text on the screen rather than the custom font.

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to use a fixed width font or put the individual digits in a custom layout with fixed widths.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/digit1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/digit2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the typeface using your custom font like this:

```
private void setLogoTypeface()
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();       
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager,"GILB.TTF");        
    logo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    logo.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

Substitute your font name and the textview should render the font.